# Can't upgrade to PostGIS 2.2

Tags: postgis, postgresql, database, sfcgal

I am running on MAC OSX El Capitan. My version of postgres is 9.4.5.0. My PostGIS version is 2.1.7. I cannot upgrade to PostGIS 2.2, because when I am trying to do, it pops "PostGIS requires SFCGAL >= 1.1.0 (found 1.0.5)". Than when I try to fix it by upgrading SFCGAL, it stops process in the steps of compiling "union.cpp" library. I have found on github, that the problem might be in the old version of Boost, so I have upgraded Boost, but the problem has preserved.

Comment: Which version of Boost are you using?  If you are compiling SFCGAL yourself, I would suggest using 1.2.0+.  1.1.0 has compile  issues with newer Boost.

Comment: I am using boost 1.58 - almost the most recent one. And still unsuccessful with upgrading sfcgal.

Comment: Yah 1.58 doesn't work with 1.1.0 SFCGAL.  Try compiling with 1.2.0 SFCGAL.  Though I think booset 1.59 might work.  Here is related ticket - https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/issues/103

Comment: I have problem, when I compile v1.59 it still uses v 1.58.

Comment: Did you try using 1.2.0 SFCGAL.  1.2.0 should work fine with 1.58 and has a lot of bugs fixed that existed in 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I should also mention, if you don't need SFCGAL support you should be able to turn off with

./configure --without-sfcgal

- functions listed here: 
  http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/reference.html#reference_sfcgal (ST_3DIntersects and some other functions also have different behavior if backend is set to sfcgal)
- functions affected you'll see with a 1/2 3D thingy http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_TypeFunctionMatrix (are functions built into PostGIS but are enhanced when backend=sfcgal or just behave differently).